# The MPN ID you provided (XXXXXX) does not exist, or you do not have access to it. Please provide a valid MPN ID and try again]

Tags: azure, entra-id

I am getting this error when I am trying to add MPNID to an Azure Application Registration. No documentation regarding this issue

The MPN ID you provided (XXXXXX) does not exist, or you do not have access to it. Please provide a valid MPN ID and try again. [VFSMWUDu8KWgEx8CQ8Djg7]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of MPNID - Local and Global. I was trying Local MPNID

Try Global MPNID [image]